# What is the difference between analytical method and numerical method in DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I have the two examples below, both find the solution of the differential equation at t = 0.004. The first one uses analytical method and the answer is correct, while the second one uses numerical method based on the given parameters A and B.

```
(* Ex.1 *)
Clear["Global`*"]
DSolve[{y'[t] == -2 A*y[t] + 2 E^(-2 A*t) B^2 t, y[0] == 0}, {y[t]}, 
  t] /. {t -> 0.004, A -> 252.5 + 2499.75 I, B -> 0.505 + 2.474 I}

(* Ex.2 *)
Clear["Global`*"]
A = 252.5 + 2499.75 I;
B = 0.505 + 2.474 I;
DSolve[{y'[t] == -2 A*y[t] + 2 E^(-2 A*t) B^2 t, y[0] == 0}, {y[t]}, 
  t] /. t -> 0.004
```

Here are the outputs for these examples

Ex. 1

```
{{y[0.004] -> -2.65742*10^-7 + 0.0000135297 I}}
```

Ex. 2

```
{{y[0.004] -> -4.24866*10^9 + 4.68919*10^9 I}}
```

I know I can avoid this problem by using NDSolve, but I still want to understand why these two results can be so different. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always rationalize my input when using exact solvers. This seems to be due to a side effect of Mathematica's DSolve not doing that. You should not be using inexact numbers with exact solvers. This is known issue (many examples on this forum like this), and can sometimes lead to floating point problems like here.

I agree that DSolve result when given inexact numbers is off. But you are not using `DSolve` correctly actually.

Lets compare the ode first with the same ode in Maple

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A = 252.5 + 2499.75 I;
B = 0.505 + 2.474 I;
ode = y'[t] == -2 A*y[t] + 2 E^(-2 A*t) B^2 t
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
A:=252.5+2499.75*I;
B:=0.505+2.474*I;
ode:=diff(y(t),t)=-2*A*y(t)+2*exp(-2*A*t)*B^2*t;
```

[image]

So far, no difference. Same exact input. Lets solve it now in DSolve and dsolve and look at the output. No IC is needed. Just the general solution

```
sol=DSolveValue[ode,y[t],t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol:=dsolve(ode);
```

[image]

You see the difference. Mathematica `DSolve` did not rationalize the input. While Maple did.

This causes floating point approximation to carry over during the solution in some unpredictable ways.  You can see this effect by comparing the two solutions at $t=0.004$

```
A:=252.5+2499.75*I;
B:=0.505+2.474*I;
ode:=diff(y(t),t)=-2*A*y(t)+2*exp(-2*A*t)*B^2*t;
ic:=y(0)=0;
eval(rhs(dsolve([ode,ic])),t=0.004)
```

Gives

```
-2.657424776*10^(-7) + 0.00001352973579*I
```

While Mathematica's is

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A = 252.5 + 2499.75 I;
B = 0.505 + 2.474 I;
ode = y'[t] == -2 A*y[t] + 2 E^(-2 A*t) B^2 t
sol = DSolveValue[{ode, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t] /. t -> 0.004
```

gives

```
-4.24866*10^9+4.68919*10^9 I
```

As to why this happens with `DSolve` and not `NDSolve`, well, may be because `DSolve` is designed to expect exact input.

A workaround is to simply use exact numbers:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A = Rationalize[252.5 + 2499.75 I]
B = Rationalize[0.505 + 2.474 I]
ode = y'[t] == -2 A*y[t] + 2 E^(-2 A*t) B^2 t
sol = DSolveValue[{ode, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t] /. t -> 0.004
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]